# curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to storage.googleapis.com:443

Tags: android, git, repo

I try to download Repo using my Mac bash at home, but I get this response:

```
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to storage.googleapis.com:443
```

[Picture I interrupted from Mac Bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im4GU.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

### It was my router issue

Please check your router to see if it is doing a transparent proxy for you?

If it is, then you may want to turn that off.

If you can't turn it off, then you might want to install a VPN solution that will allow you to bypass it.

Just a thought.

Just got this solution from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1264498/homebrew-gives-ssl-error-ssl-error-syscall-on-home-network)

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to your curl version.

According to
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=175433
downgrading curl to 7.33.0-3 should help.

The original bug is tracked here: http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1319/